# Set a power automate trigger condition to only allow flow to run if power bi data array = 1

Tags: json, powerbi, power-automate

I'm attempting to use power automate visual in power BI to make a button that updates an item on a SharePoint list. I'm able to make the flow work however I am attempting to use trigger conditions inside of the power BI step of the flow to only allow the flow to run when the array from power BI only includes one item. In theory this should prevent someone accidentally not selecting an item in the report and hitting the button then updating all of the items on the SharePoint list. I've tried many iterations and I cannot seem to find one that works thank you.

```
@equals(triggerOutputs()?Length (['body/entity/PowerBIvalues']),1)
```

Comment: Can you provide the trigger body in the question?  I see a few issues but need to clarify the JSON data first.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the length function around the attribute. But triggerOutputs() is part of that attribute reference. So, it looks like the length function is in the wrong place.

Can you try the below trigger condition expression instead?

```
@equals(length(triggerOutputs()?['body/entity/PowerBIvalues']),1)
```